# Repricing SOFR Quotes and Non-Zero NPV

Tags: quantlib, yield-curve, interest-rate-swap, sofr

I generated/calibrated a SOFR Curve using Quantlib Python and would like to know why when repricing the swaps have non-zero NPVs. Appreciate any assistance. Thank you.

**Parameters**

```python
mktDate = ql.Date(8,3,2021)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = mktDate
Settlement = 2
Calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
DayCount = ql.Actual360()
```

**OIS Curve Helper**

```python
oisHelper = []
for quote in marketQuotes:
    oisHelper.append(ql.OISRateHelper(Settlement, ql.Period(quote[0]), 
ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(quote[1]/100)), ql.Sofr()))
```

**Curve Specification**

```python
sofrCurve = ql.PiecewiseLinearZero(Settlement, Calendar, oisHelper, DayCount)
valCurve = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(sofrCurve)
sofrIndex = ql.Sofr(valCurve)
swapEngine = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(valCurve)
```

**Reprice Quotes**

```python
for quote in marketQuotes:
    start = Calendar.advance(mktDate, Settlement, ql.Days)
    schedule = ql.MakeSchedule(start, Calendar.advance(start, ql.Period(quote[0])), ql.Period('1Y'), calendar = Calendar)
    fixedRate = quote[1]/100
    oisSwap = ql.OvernightIndexedSwap(
        ql.OvernightIndexedSwap.Receiver, 
        1E6, 
        schedule, 
        fixedRate, 
        DayCount,
        sofrIndex)
    oisSwap.setPricingEngine(swapEngine)
    print(quote, round(oisSwap.NPV(),3))
```

**Output**

```
('1W', 0.01982) 0.0
('2W', 0.02394) -0.0
('3W', 0.02503) -0.0
('1M', 0.02897) -0.0
('3M', 0.037) 0.0
('4M', 0.041) -0.0
('5M', 0.043) 0.0
('6M', 0.04597) 0.0
('7M', 0.04797) 0.0
('8M', 0.04997) -0.0
('9M', 0.05197) 0.0
('10M', 0.0535) 0.0
('11M', 0.055) 0.0
('1Y', 0.0565) -0.0
('15M', 0.06) -0.0
('18M', 0.069) 0.003
('21M', 0.083) 0.004
('2Y', 0.10403) 0.0
('3Y', 0.27409) 0.049
('4Y', 0.50109) -0.0
('5Y', 0.718) -0.0
('6Y', 0.90703) 0.0
('7Y', 1.066) -0.0
('8Y', 1.19203) 0.83
('9Y', 1.29306) 0.521
('10Y', 1.37903) -0.0
('12Y', 1.51294) -0.0
('15Y', 1.63591) -0.0
('20Y', 1.72494) 0.766
('25Y', 1.75318) 1.322
('30Y', 1.76979) -0.0
('40Y', 1.71094) 0.0
('50Y', 1.63649) -0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference probably comes from not having exactly the same conventions.
When you use `ql.MakeOIS` all the conventions will come from the `ql.Sofr` index, but when you build the Instrument manually with `ql.OvernightIndexedSwap` you are entering all the convention by hand, namely for the schedule.

The `ql.MakeSchedule` class has many more parameters which mostly default to None:

- convention=None
- terminalDateConvention=None,
- rule=None
- forwards=False
- backwards=False,
- endOfMonth=None
- firstDate=None
- nextToLastDate=None

Comment: Thank you David. Appreciate the feedback. I will test each parameter.

Comment: Still struggling. I tried various configurations with the parameters with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to work when using ql.MakeOIS. Still need to understand why there is a discrepancy. Any thoughts?

**Reprice Quotes**

```python
for quote in marketQuotes:
    swapTenor = ql.Period(quote[0])
    fixedRate = quote[1]/100
    oisSwap = ql.MakeOIS(swapTenor, sofrIndex, fixedRate, nominal=1E6)
    print(quote, round(oisSwap.NPV(),3))
```

**Output**

```
('1W', 0.01982) 0.0
('2W', 0.02394) 0.0
('3W', 0.02503) 0.0
('1M', 0.02897) 0.0
('3M', 0.037) -0.0
('4M', 0.041) 0.0
('5M', 0.043) 0.0
('6M', 0.04597) 0.0
('7M', 0.04797) 0.0
('8M', 0.04997) 0.0
('9M', 0.05197) -0.0
('10M', 0.0535) -0.0
('11M', 0.055) -0.0
('1Y', 0.0565) 0.0
('15M', 0.06) 0.0
('18M', 0.069) 0.0
('21M', 0.083) -0.0
('2Y', 0.10403) -0.0
('3Y', 0.27409) -0.0
('4Y', 0.50109) 0.0
('5Y', 0.718) 0.0
('6Y', 0.90703) -0.0
('7Y', 1.066) 0.0
('8Y', 1.19203) -0.0
('9Y', 1.29306) -0.0
('10Y', 1.37903) 0.0
('12Y', 1.51294) 0.0
('15Y', 1.63591) 0.0
('20Y', 1.72494) 0.0
('25Y', 1.75318) 0.0
('30Y', 1.76979) 0.0
('40Y', 1.71094) 0.0
('50Y', 1.63649) 0.0
```

Comment: I'd check the code of the `MakeOIS` class to see the defaults it uses: https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/master/ql/instruments/makeois.cpp

Comment: Thank you Luigi, I will have a look.

Comment: If some are repricing but not others, it could be the direction of the schedule. For the 18M for example check the stub is at the front or end in both the bootstrap and repricing.